# Anaconda spyder ide Theme

Tags: anaconda, themes, spyder

I used to have my theme as monokai and literally everything was monokai. I updated spyder and now when I change the theme to monokai, only the console and editor are monokai. Everything else is standard spyder dark mode. Like the menu bar etc... How do I make EVERYTHING monokai. This is windows spyder 4. Tools-preferences-appearance allows me to change synax highlited theme to monokai but, again, this is only changing the editor and the console.

Comment: Anyone? I know it is possible because my old setup was like this. I remember it not being straightforward though.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't know what you did before to make everything to follow the Monokai theme, but that's simply not possible now, sorry. We'll try to add support for this use case in the future, but it can pass a year or more before it happens.